# Thread-safe using of <random>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, random, thread-safety

STL said on [his lecture on Going Native](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), that

> Multiple threads **cannot** simultaneously call a single object.

(Last slide on [pptx file online](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3a%2f%2fvideo.ch9.ms%2fsessions%2fgonat%2f2013%2fSTLGN13rand.pptx).)

If I need uniform distribution of random numbers across multiple threads (not independent random generators for threads), how to correctly use the same `uniform_int_distribution` from multiple threads? Or it is not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never meant to use a PRNG for long enough that you can see a perfectly uniform distribution from it.  You should only see a random approximation of a uniform distribution.  The fact that giving every thread its own PRNG means it would take `numThreads` times longer for every thread to see that perfect distribution does not matter.

PRNGs are subject to mathematical analysis to confirm that they produce each possible output the same number of times, but this does not reflect how they're meant to be used.

If they were used this way it would represent a *weakness*.  If you watch it for long enough you know that having seen output `x` `n` times, and every other output `n+1` times, the next output must be `x`.  This is uniform but it is obviously not random.

A true RNG will never produce a perfectly uniform output, but it should also never show the same bias twice.  A PRNG known to have non-uniform output will have the same non-uniform output every time it's used.  This means that if you run simulations for longer to average out the noise, the PRNG's own bias will eventually become the most statistically significant factor.  So an ideal PRNG should eventually emit a perfectly uniform distribution (actually often not perfect, but within a known, very small margin) over a *sufficiently long period*.

Your random seed will pick a random point somewhere in that sequence and your random number requests will proceed some way along that sequence, but if you ever find yourself going all the way around and coming back to your own start point (or even within 1/10th that distance) then you need to get a bigger PRNG.

That said, there is another consideration.  Often PRNGs are used specifically so that their results will be predictable.

If you're in a situation where you need a mutex to safely access a single PRNG, then you've probably already lost your predictable behaviour because you can't tell which thread got the next [predictable] random number.  Each thread still sees an unpredictable sequence because you can't be sure which subset of PRNG results it got.

If every thread has its own PRNG, then (so long as other ordering constraints are met as necessary) you can still get predictable results.

Answer (score 3):

Just create multiple copies. A distribution is a lightweight object, cheaper than the mutex you'd need to protect it.

Comment: But if `uniform_int_distribution` will be created every time and destroyed after generation, then how this guarantees uniform distribution?

Comment: @vladon: I actually meant one per thread, not one per random number!

Comment: @vladon if each distribution is random and uniform and you pick a single element of each, then the set of these element is uniformly distributed as well.

Comment: @MSalters but I need one uniformity per application, across all threads

Comment: @tobi303 is there mathematical proof of it? If we have several billions of random generated numbers in 100 threads in 100 generators, will they all be uniformed?

Comment: Why not just try it for whichever numbers of threads, generators and samples you're really concerned about? Then you can tell us if there's some counter-intuitive bias.

Comment: @vladon from mathematics it definitely is true when the distributions are independent. So in practice you have to take make sure that they get independent seeds. Anyhow, as Useless pointed out, you cannot get true randomness from a pseudo random generator and you should just try and check if the distribution fits your needs.

Comment: @vladon: The idea that past outcomes are relevant to future chances is known as the _Gambler's fallacy_. The main thing you need to do is to use a single root RNG to seed all the per-thread RNG's. The reason is fairly simple: if you seed all RNG's the same, they will all produce the same numbers.

Comment: Very dangerous advice.  An implementation of an RNG might simply permute its seed to produce the next value and use the result as its new seed.  This would start all the RNGs at nearly the same position and the results would be very predictable.  Better to use `seed+i`, incrementing `i` for each thread.

Comment: @sh1: That's not how the C++ RNG's work. (It would be a good advice for the old, poor quality C RNG's)

Comment: `linear_congruential` is still an offering in <random>, and LC can also be used to stretch seeds for other generators.  Worst possible case is that by using two adjacent stages of an LCG for seeds you end up seeding two instances of a heavyweight generator with almost the same data rotated by 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) storage when defining your random generator engine (assuming you want to have only one declared in your program). In this way, each thread will have access to a "local" copy of it, so you won't have any data races. You cannot just use a single engine across all threads, since you may have data races conditions when changing the state of it during the generation sequence.

Comment: problem is not in race condition, but in uniformity of random generation across threads

Comment: @vladon having multiple independent generators is equivalent as generating from a single one (provided you use different seeds).

Comment: Is it intuitive assumption, or may be there is mathematical proof of it?

Comment: @vladon I'm pretty sure there is some proof of it, although don't have one at this point. One route to go: define `Z = \vect{X} = (X1, ..., Xn)`, where `X_i` are your independent uniformly-distributed random variables. Then prove that `Z` is uniformly distributed (in other words, all points in the hypercube are equally probable). It is true, since the probability of each outcome is just the product of the probabilities, so all outcomes are equally-probable. This will probably do it.